# Downloading Xcode for 11.7 macOS Big Sur

Tags: flutter, xcode

I’m trying to download Flutter but I need to download Xcode before I do that. But, I can't download it from App Store because my MacBook is old and is running Big Sur. But Xcode in the App Store version currently requires macOS 13.5 and above. And Flutter requires Xcode 14 or higher:

```
Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.2)
    ✗ Flutter requires Xcode 14 or higher.
      Download the latest version or update via the Mac App Store.
```

I am trying to download Xcode from the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a developer account, you can download old Xcode versions from [Apple’s developer download site](https://developer.apple.com/download/all/?q=Xcode%2014) using a web browser. See [Apple’s Xcode support page](https://developer.apple.com/support/xcode/) for OS requirements.

---

I know this is not the answer you were hoping for, but regarding Big Sur (macOS 11) and Xcode 14, note that according to that [Xcode support page](https://developer.apple.com/support/xcode/), Xcode 14.0.x requires macOS Monterey (macOS 12.5) and versions 14.3 and later require Ventura (macOS 13) or later.

Finally, ignoring Flutter requirements, be aware that, as of April 2023, [submissions to the app store require Xcode 14.1 and later](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=jd9wcyov), as well. This minimum requirement changes on an annual basis, so prepare yourself for these requirements being updated further in the coming months. You might want to keep an eye on their [upcoming requirements page](https://developer.apple.com/news/upcoming-requirements/).